# Spring-WS: How to send an already enveloped message?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, spring-ws

I implementing a Spring-WS web service client and I send a request without unmarshaling because I am sending a ready-made signed (wssec) request with all SOAP wrappers.

**For example:**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <wsse:Security wsu:Id="Id-sec-98b44dc4123d94b309db4e47881c48c0cfde" SOAP-ENV:actor="http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/actors/smev">
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="Id-sig-02747f3e4b2c3afbd9ee0c47b82df6ce1ce1">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:cpxmlsec:algorithms:gostr34102012-gostr34112012-256"/>
                    <Reference URI="#Id-wssecdata-d8392bad08e2095ea110d7ebdf6cb20b77f0" Id="Id-dataref-2f98695f5d03929ba61e8553e17275e99ea0">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:cpxmlsec:algorithms:gostr34112012-256"/>
                        <DigestValue>DIGECT</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>SIG_VALUE</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo Id="Id-keyinfo-60c321e68eba4e0b869013c3b661a255d39a">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="Id-strT8lVAuhyhE9ORsox">
                        <wsse:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#Id-bstKf4S_QPNjJpr839_"/>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" wsu:Id="Id-bstKf4S_QPNjJpr839_">CERT</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body wsu:Id="Id-wssecdata-d8392bad08e2095ea110d7ebdf6cb20b77f0">
        <Message/>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But according to the algorithm defined in the [Spring-WS documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/api/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate.html), Spring-WS additionally wraps my request in envelopes by calling the `createWebServiceMessage()` in `WebServiceTemplate`.

**The sent result is as follows:**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <SOAP-ENV:Header>
                <wsse:Security wsu:Id="Id-sec-98b44dc4123d94b309db4e47881c48c0cfde" SOAP-ENV:actor="http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/actors/smev">
                    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="Id-sig-02747f3e4b2c3afbd9ee0c47b82df6ce1ce1">
                        <SignedInfo>
                            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:cpxmlsec:algorithms:gostr34102012-gostr34112012-256"/>
                            <Reference URI="#Id-wssecdata-d8392bad08e2095ea110d7ebdf6cb20b77f0" Id="Id-dataref-2f98695f5d03929ba61e8553e17275e99ea0">
                                <Transforms>
                                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                                </Transforms>
                                <DigestMethod Algorithm="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:cpxmlsec:algorithms:gostr34112012-256"/>
                                <DigestValue>DIGECT</DigestValue>
                            </Reference>
                        </SignedInfo>
                        <SignatureValue>SIG_VALUE</SignatureValue>
                        <KeyInfo Id="Id-keyinfo-60c321e68eba4e0b869013c3b661a255d39a">
                            <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="Id-strT8lVAuhyhE9ORsox">
                                <wsse:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#Id-bstKf4S_QPNjJpr839_"/>
                            </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                        </KeyInfo>
                    </Signature>
                    <wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" wsu:Id="Id-bstKf4S_QPNjJpr839_">CERT</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
                </wsse:Security>
            </SOAP-ENV:Header>
            <SOAP-ENV:Body wsu:Id="Id-wssecdata-d8392bad08e2095ea110d7ebdf6cb20b77f0">
                <Message/>
            </SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**And this is how I do it:**

```
public void callWebService(String request) {
    StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(request));
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
    getWebServiceTemplate().sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(source, webServiceMessage -> {
        SaajSoapMessage saajMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) webServiceMessage;
        saajMessage.setSoapAction(SOAP_ACTION);
    }, result);
```

It seems to me that using SAAJ will not help. How can I send my request? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution on my own. It consists in build a new SAAJ message and replacing it with the old one. I hope someone will be helpful.

```
public void callWebService(String request) {
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(request));
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

        getWebServiceTemplate().sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(source, webServiceMessage -> {
            SaajSoapMessage saajSoapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) webServiceMessage;
            try {
                SOAPPart soapPart = saajSoapMessage.getSaajMessage().getSOAPPart();
                SOAPBody soapBody = soapPart.getEnvelope().getBody();
                Document innerSoapBody = soapBody.extractContentAsDocument();

                //Строим новое SAAJ-сообщение for webServiceMessage
                MessageFactory soapMessageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
                SOAPMessage soapMessage = soapMessageFactory.createMessage();
                soapMessage.getSOAPPart().setContent(new DOMSource(innerSoapBody));

                ((SaajSoapMessage) webServiceMessage).setSaajMessage(soapMessage);
            } catch (SOAPException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Can't rebuild WebServiceMessage in SMEV2 invoke!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Передаим корректный SOAP-Action.
            saajSoapMessage.setSoapAction(SMEV2_SOAP_ACTION);
        }, result);
```